# MySql multiple databases. How to insert?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 databases I want to update a field (insert?) uuid in table fe_accounts of database feDB, so that NULL i rplaced buy uuid from the table NameHistory in databse NameHistoryDB.

Database 1

```
Database : NameHistoryDB
Table: NameHistory

+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| uuid                                 | playername       | dateadded           | lastseen            |
+--------------------------------------+------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 0b9bb8dc-051c-4d8d-9029-96d969baece1 | xRazmuz          | 2014-04-09 08:40:47 | 2014-04-15 12:32:40 |
| a61925ba-8a69-464b-89c9-37d3d3fe9ce4 | Sleepyangel99    | 2014-04-09 08:45:09 | 2014-05-05 11:50:38 |
| 3983c0ef-3def-4f1b-ac15-335d6a4e1458 | pulle3           | 2014-04-09 08:51:37 | 2014-04-26 16:48:34 |
| 502f873d-7bf6-4187-bcf1-a5d78f574293 | zohan10          | 2014-04-09 09:04:37 | 2014-04-22 17:07:24 |
```

Database 2

```
Database : feDB
Table: fe_accounts

+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| name             | money   | uuid                                 |
+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| xRazmuz          |      74 | NULL                                 |
| Sleepyangel99    |    2650 | NULL                                 |
| pulle3           |    1000 | NULL                                 |
| zohan10          |    1079 | NULL                                 |
```

I want to insert the uuid from  database 2 to database 1, so the result will be like this:

```
Database : feDB
Table: fe_accounts

+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| name             | money   | uuid                                 |
+------------------+---------+--------------------------------------+
| xRazmuz          |      74 | 0b9bb8dc-051c-4d8d-9029-96d969baece1 |
| Sleepyangel99    |    2650 | a61925ba-8a69-464b-89c9-37d3d3fe9ce4 |
| pulle3           |    1000 | 3983c0ef-3def-4f1b-ac15-335d6a4e1458 |
| zohan10          |    1079 | 502f873d-7bf6-4187-bcf1-a5d78f574293 |
```

How do i do that?

Comment: You could use qualified name. Like DB.TABLE.COLUMN

Comment: use "database" (the name of your database)
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/use.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do is to JOIN the tables from two databases and then update as

```
update feDB.fe_accounts db2
inner join NameHistoryDB.NameHistory db1 on db1.playername =  db2.name
set
db2.uuid = db1.uuid
where 
db2.uuid is null
```

> NOTE : To run the above query you need proper permission i.e. mysql
>   user having access to both DB.
>
> Also it will match with the payername, there is no other common key to
>   match so accurate update lies in having unique player names

Answer (score 0):

Run these two queries serially:

```
USE feDB;
UPDATE
fe_accounts 
JOIN NameHistoryDB.NameHistory t2 ON playername=name
SET uuid=NameHistoryDB.NameHistory.uuid
WHERE uuid IS NULL;
```